# Node.js/Express SSR Error: 'ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, seo, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to implement server-side rendering (SSR) for a React application using Node.js and Express. However, I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve. Here are the details of the issue:

```
    throw fatalError;
    ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at getUrlBasedHistory (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\@remix-run\router\history.ts:606:18)
    at Object.createBrowserHistory (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\@remix-run\router\history.ts:378:10)
    at BrowserRouter (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-router-dom\index.tsx:361:26)
    at renderWithHooks (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5662:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5735:15)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5950:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6108:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6080:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5789:7)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5950:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6108:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6080:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5789:7)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5950:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6108:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6080:14)
    at renderContextProvider (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5924:3)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6021:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6108:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6080:14)
    at renderContextProvider (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5924:3)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6021:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6108:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6080:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5789:7)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5950:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6108:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6080:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5789:7)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5950:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6108:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6080:14)
    at retryTask (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6532:5)
    at performWork (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6580:7)
    at C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6904:12
    at scheduleWork (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:78:3)
    at startWork (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6903:3)
    at renderToStringImpl (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6977:3)
    at Object.renderToString (C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:7065:10)
    at C:\Users\SilverPoint\Documents\SEO-SSR\spog_print\server\/server.js:18:33
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)
```

```
// index.js
require("ignore-styles");

require("@babel/register")({
    "ignore": ["node_modules"],
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
});

require("./server");
```

```
// server.js

import express from "express";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";
import App from "../src/App";

const app = express();

app.use("^/$", (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(path.resolve("./build/index.html"), "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.err(err);
      return res.status(500).send("Some error happened");
    }

    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>
    );

    return res.send(
      data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${html}</div>`)
    );
  });
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build")));

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("App is launched on PORT : 4000");
});
```

```
//this is the code for client index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import './i18n';
import { AppProvider } from './context/AppContext';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
      <HelmetProvider>
        <App />
      </HelmetProvider>
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

What could be causing this 'document is not defined' error in a Node.js/Express SSR setup?
How can I resolve this error and successfully implement server-side rendering for my React application?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!